# Oil leaking, bad valve cover?

Tags: engine, nissan, oil-leak, sentra

I noticed that my oil was empty 4 days after it was full. There is oil residue on the top of the engine and on the inside of the hood. I am wondering if this could be from a bad valve cover. It is a 2002 Nissan Sentra GXE. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anyway we could tell you definitely that is what the problem is ... we'd need more information and pictures. A better bet is for you to look closer and discover where the is coming from. If you look on the ground, is there oil showing up to the front or the rear of the vehicle? Is this new behavior (did it just start)? Did you change oils (brand or weight)? Is the oil drain plug tight? When you say "empty" what exactly do you mean? Please edit your question and throw *any* pertinent information into your question so we can better help you.

Comment: I haven't noticed any oil on the ground, I did notice that it blew out a little bit of white smoke when my husband drove it home the other day, only when he was getting on interstate but haven't noticed it since. We just purchased the car 5 days ago and I am afraid we hav been dupped but if it is something that we can fix then of course I am all for that. I see oil on top of the motor around where the spark plug wires are attached to the motor and it looks like it has been slung around the engine and the top of the hood. It was real clean when we got it. (Of course)  hope its not a head gasket

Comment: Well it definitely sounds like a leak if all of this has happened in 4 days. Where do you think the oil is concentrated ... towards the passenger side of the car (assuming a left hand drive or US car)? Your best bet may be to clean the entire underhood area until it's spotless, then run the vehicle and *see* where the oil is coming from. Also, again, pictures would be entirely helpful here.

Comment: Also check the bolts holding the valve cover on and make sure they are all there.  These are notorious for stripping out from overtightening by zealous home mechanics who don't use 1/4" torque wrenches.  Torque should be only 70-85 in-lb (NOT ft-lb). 3/8" torque wrenches can't do that. Overtightening will  make the valve cover gaskets leak, and not torquing them will, too.